# Перенос координат на карту yandex или google с помощью Python

Tags: python-3.x, yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api

возникла необходимость с помощью Python добавлять метки на карту Yandex или Google. Суть программы такая, пользователи отправляют свою геопозицию(долгота и широта) посредством Telegram бота, задача программы добавить метку текущей позиции пользователя и метку магазина(забита константой). Было бы не плохо если бы подсказали какую библиотеку использовать или что почитать в данном направлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователь вводит широту и долготу. На Python можно получить эти значения и сформировать GeoJson с точкой и атрибутами:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "user_name"
  }
}
```

Затем из Python передаём на frontend. Отображаем GeoJson с помощью JS на карте. У яндекса могут быть с этим проблемы. Если используется Гугл:

```
GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), geoJsonData);
```

Нужно обратить внимание на систему координат. Широта и долгота должна быть в WGS84 epsg4326.
На Python специальные библиотеки использовать не обязательно. На JS почитайте документацию Google maps.